# CURL and php pdf file transfer from one server to another

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I am trying to build a pdf file in server B and trying to transfer back the built pdf file in server A.

This is the code I have in server A

```
  $tuCurl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.server_B/test.php");
  curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $package);
  curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  $result=  curl_exec($tuCurl);
  curl_close($tuCurl);
```

I have all the necessary code to build a pdf file in server B(The header is at server B

```
 header('Cache-Control: public');
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $filename);
 header('Content-Length: '.strlen($result));
 echo $result;
```

). The only problem I have now is to download it back at server A.

Any ideas how we can accomplish that without having to print the header at server A?

Comment: Why is the requirement not to set the headers at server A? A simple solution would be just to set them at A as well & be done with it. If you don't know the headers beforehand & need them to be set by B, your simplest solution at A is not using PHP, but just to proxy the request in the webserver config to B. More cumbersome is to request the reponse headers to be in the `$result` from curl, split them out, possibly parse them, and call `header()`'s with that data again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the headers before echoing it.

Search for the first occurance of \n\n and remove everything before that including the double line break.

or try adding this to A:

```
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```